# QML object property inside transform

Tags: qml

I have an object which I want to rotate about a point whose coordinates are stored in the properties `offsetx`, `offsety`. Here's my object:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rec1
    property int offsetx: width/2
    property int offsety: height/2
    height: 50
    width: 50
    color: "blue"
    x: originx - offsetx
    y: originy - offsety
    transform: Rotation { origin.x: offsetx ; origin.y: offsety; angle: 45}
}
```

The transform will recognize neither `offsetx` nor `offsety`, whereas the position properties x,y, which both depend on the offset properties, work fine. If I write `rec1.offsetx` then the transform recognizes it, but using this method might be a problem if I want to instantiate many of these rectangles (which wont necessarily have an id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move above code in a separate `qml` file.
Each `qml` file has at least one root item which its properties are available for its children without explicitly qualification.
**SampleRect.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Rectangle {
    id: rec1
    property int offsetx: width/2
    property int offsety: height/2
    height: 50
    width: 50
    color: "blue"
    x: 100 - offsetx
    y: 100 - offsety
    transform: Rotation { origin.x: offsetx ; origin.y: offsety; angle: 45}  //<- offsetx is accessible. same as rec1.offsetx
}
```

**use it in main.qml file as**

```
SampleRect {
}
```